# How to convert postgres number to a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date column that has the date formatted as follow... however I'm not sure what format that number represents for the date.  how can I get in yyyy-mm-dd format?

[image]

Comment: What date is 43983?

Comment: Looks like an [Excel date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818243/convert-excel-date-format-to-regular-date-with-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I think that @horse_with_no_name is correct and it most probably is excel date. So it could be days from 1899-12-30 not 1900-01-01

I can't say for sure but those numbers looks like days from  '1899-12-30' (it's better to ask developers/check documentation actually)

44013 / 365 - looks like 120 years, so it looks like dates from 2020

Look

```sql
WITH days (days) AS (
VALUES(44103),(44105), (44078)
)
SELECT days, 
        '1899-31-30'::DATE + days *'1 day'::INTERVAL AS date
    FROM days
```

| days | date |
| --- | --- |
| 44103 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 |
| 44105 | 2020-10-03 00:00:00 |
| 44078 | 2020-09-06 00:00:00 |

Comment: Thanks! yeah I believe it's excel funky format too.  I sent back to vendor. believe it happened when they change it to xlsx